# In which part of Django application a user is made authenticated?

Tags: django

I am trying to restrict multiple logins by a user with the use of sessions
Below is my code

**my model**

```
    class LoggedInUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name='logged_in_user', on_delete =models.CASCADE)
        session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**my middlware**

```
ef MySessionMiddleware(get_response):
  
    def my_function(request):
  
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                user = LoggedInUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            except:
                user = LoggedInUser.objects.create(user=request.user)
            
             if user.session_key:
                 #check whether old key is same as current
                 print('here inside user.session_key')
                 if user.session_key != request.session.session_key:
                    return JsonResponse("you already have a active session kindly logout from that", 
                            status=400, safe=False)
             user.session_key = request.session.session_key
             user.save()
                
        response = get_response(request)
                
        return response
    return my_function
```

**my middleware setting**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'pwned_passwords_django.middleware.PwnedPasswordsMiddleware',
    'oneFA.middlewares.password_validator_middleware',
    'oneFA.middlewares.MySessionMiddleware',
]
```

**my logic**

I created a model which stores a user with OnetoOne field with CustomUSer which is my authenticated model, and a session key then everytime i made a call i am trying to check the current session key with previous one and if it is not same then a user is trying to login again so i am returning error

**my error**

request.user.is_authenticated is always coming false which means that user is not authenticated now , i even tried placing my middleware ahead of authentication middleware and doing my work after response has been made i.e. in the returning cycle when every middleware is called again but it is  giving me same, so i need help when a user is authenticated so that i can check session key or a change needs to done in my approach

Comment: **One note :** why do you create a new user in the except block if the user is authenticated ? An authenticated user is a user already created, so you don't have to use `try except` bloc. Just `user = LoggedInUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()` is enough

Comment: Yes user is authenticated but loggedIn user model is not my default authentication model, i have defined another CustomUser model for authentication purposes so i have to manually add a object in LoggedIn user model